# Mysql2 - Node js - Object response

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql2

When I run a sql query, lets say:
 `SELECT * FROM USER LIMIT 1`
Mysql2 return in [columns,rows]. Instead is there any way, where I get object as result like
{column_name:val}

Eg:
{
Name: Kshitij
Age: 22
}

I already know the looping system where I can run a for loop on keys in result and create an object, But instead Im looking for a direct solution like associative array in PHP

Comment: Have you configured it with `rowsAsArray: true`? Because from the docs it seems that the default format is objects like what you want..

Comment: the result of promise .query() is [rows, columns] where each row in rows array is already in the format you need eg { Name: Kshitij Age: 22 }. Even when there is on row in the response the rows is an array, just with one item in it